# Number of numbers which have the order $p$ is $\varphi (p)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Theorem: Let $p$ be a prime number. Then, the number of numbers  $\leq p$ which have the order $d$, where $d | p-1$, modulo $p$, is $\varphi ( d)$.

Note: This is not the whole proof, I wrote only the implication I couldn't understand. I think the rest of it is not necessary.

Proof: Let $\psi (d)$ be the number of numbers $\leq p$ which have the order $d$. Since the order of every number from $\left\{ 1,...,p-1 \right\}$ divides $p-1$, then $\sum_{d | p-1} \psi (d)=p-1$. I don't understand this implication, can anyone explain it to me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{d | p-1} \psi (d)$

Since order of a number is unique, you can assign the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ to `disjoint` bins based on orders. Each number belongs to exactly one bin, and each bin contains all the numbers with same order. (For example, say the `bin_d` contains all the numbers of order `d`, then there will be exactly $\psi(d)$ numbers in `bin_d`)

Adding up the number of elements in each of these bins gives back the total number of elements $p-1$.

---

If it helps, imagine this situation: There are a bunch of candies on table. When you count them you get 100.  Next your sister puts them in different baskets based on the color. Then she counts the number of candies in each basket and adds them. She gets 100 too. Nothing fancy!

Comment: thank you thank you!

Comment: yw:)................